# Swift MobileVLCKit how to set UserAgent?

Tags: swift, vlc

I want to set custom User Agent in the video player app using MobileVLCKit.
But I am not sure how to set it in version 3.3.16.
If anyone had a experience in it, please let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for that.

```
let vlcPlayer: VLCMediaPlayer =
{
    let player = VLCMediaPlayer()
    return player
}()
let user_agent = "Your user agent"

guard let url = URL(string: "video_url") else { return }
let vlcMedia = vlcMedia(url: url)
vlcMedia.addOption(":http-user-agent=\(user_agent)") // add here
vlcPlayer.media = vlcMedia
vlcPlayer.drawable = player_view
vlcPlayer.delegate = self
vlcPlayer.play()
```

We can add any options in [https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/) by using addOption function.